# How to accept id of javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

My form is like this

[image: social network]

After login a user, enter the id of social networks with `@` for example `@web` or `@test`...

How to create validate for show the user, for example:

> Please enter first with @, for example @test

blade

```
function dynamicSocial (number) {
    let html = '' +
        '<div class="col-md-6 position-relative">\n' +
        '<i class="fas fa-times text-danger position-absolute"></i>' +
        '<div class="row">\n' +
        '<div class="col-md-4">\n' +
        '<div class="form-group">\n' +
        '<label for="social_id">Social Network</label>\n' +
        '<select id="social_id" name="social_id[]" class="form-control">\n' +
        '@foreach($socials as $social)\n'+
        '<option value="{{ $social->id }}">\n' +
        '{{ $social->name }}\n' +
        '</option>\n' +
        '@endforeach\n ' +
        '</select>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '<div class="col-md-8">\n' +
        '<div class="form-group">\n' +
        '<label for="link">Profile ID</label>\n' +
        '<input id="link" name="link[]" class="form-control">\n' +
        '<span class="linkErr"></span>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>';
    $('#showSocial').append(html);
}
```

js

```
var next_step = false;
parent_fieldset.find('input[id="link"]').each(function() {
    var link;
    link = document.getElementById("link").value;
    var reg = /^@[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]*$/;
    if (reg.test(link))
    {
        next_step = true;

    }else {
        next_step = false;
        let linkErrs = document.querySelectorAll(".linkErr");
        for(linkErrs of linkErr){
            linkErr.addClass('alert alert-danger');
            linkErr.textContent = "Please enter id with @.";
        }

    }
});
```

I get this error in console

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the `for ... of` loop the wrong way around. You typed `for(linkErrs of linkErr)`, it should be `for(linkErr of linkErrs)`.

```js
var next_step = false;
parent_fieldset.find('input[id="link"]').each(function() {
    var link;
    link = document.getElementById("link").value;
    var reg = /^@[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]*$/;
    if (reg.test(link))
    {
        next_step = true;

    }else {
        next_step = false;
        let linkErrs = document.querySelectorAll(".linkErr");
        for(linkErr of linkErrs){ // here
            linkErr.classList += ' alert alert-danger'; // <-- edit again - try this
            linkErr.textContent = "Please enter id with @.";
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: I get this error. `Uncaught TypeError: linkErr.addClass is not a function`

Comment: Oh! Try replacing `linkErr.addClass(...)` with `linkErr.classList.add(...)`

Comment: I get this error again. `Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character`

Comment: Oh, apparently .add doesn't support adding multiple classes at once. I'm certain `linkErr.classList += ' alert alert-danger'` is going to work.

Comment: or `linkErr.classList.add('alert', 'alert-danger')`. Sorry for this back-and-forth